# Why GetServiceDisplayNameW() and GetServiceDisplayNameA() returns different required buffer sizes in character?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

Here is a sample code (only sample code to understand it easily, no error handling, no close handles, and so on):

```
SC_HANDLE hSCManager = ::OpenSCManager(nullptr, nullptr, 0);

DWORD buffSize = 0;
::GetServiceDisplayName(hSCManager, m_serviceName, nullptr, &buffSize);

LPTSTR buff = new TCHAR[++buffSize];
VERIFY(::GetServiceDisplayName(hSCManager, m_serviceName, buff, &buffSize));
```

My sample service has the display name of `"notepad starter"` (15 characters).

Switching between build configuations, `GetServiceDisplayName()` returns a buffer size of 30 under ANSI (`GetServiceDisplayNameA`), and 15 under UNICODE (`GetServiceDisplayNameW`).

Documentation for this API says it returns the buffer size in **characters** excluding the null terminator (not well documented, but I'm expecting the buffer size to include the null terminator in the second call).

Why is it returning different buffer sizes in different build configurations?

Comment: There's no error checking in your code. The bug is going to be in your code not in Windows. Always have the mindset that your code is wrong, don't try to blame somebody else. Next step, check for errors in the return values of your API calls.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is only sample code.

Comment: Why do you have ANSII build?

Comment: Don't ask us about code that you won't show us. Make a [mcve], with full error handling.

Comment: of course 2 error in your code. you need `LPTSTR buff = new TCHAR[++buffSize];` - you allocate `buffSize + 1` buffer size (this is correct) byt sat that you have only `buffSize` size. and you need use `hSCManager` handle in call, not `hService`

Comment: why you allocate `buffSize + 1` but say that you allocate `buffSize` ?

Comment: about ansi version `A` - here really error in api. it return wrong value (*2). but this only yet one argument not use `A` versions of api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer came after 6 month (i saw it yet after 3 years) from Raymond Chen;

> Why is it reporting a required buffer size larger than what it
> actually needs?
>
> Because character set conversion is hard.
>
> When you call the Get­Service­Display­NameA function (ANSI version),
> it forwards the call to Get­Service­Display­NameW function (Unicode
> version). If the Unicode version says, “Sorry, that buffer is too
> small; it needs to be big enough to hold N Unicode characters,” the
> ANSI version doesn’t know how many ANSI characters that translates to.
> A single Unicode character could expand to as many as two ANSI
> characters in the case where the ANSI code page is DBCS. The
> Get­Service­Display­NameA function plays it safe and takes the
> worst-case scenario that the service display name consists completely
> of Unicode characters which require two ANSI characters to represent.
>
> That’s why it over-reports the buffer size.

[devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180606-00/?p=98925](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180606-00/?p=98925)

Answer (score 3):

at first `GetServiceDisplayName` take handle to the service control manager database ( *hSCManager*) as first parameter, but not handle to service (*hService*) - so you not need open service for this task. and you not need `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS` here, but 0 is enough.

however your main error in next. you allocate buffer `new TCHAR[buffSize + 1]` - so `buffSize + 1` in character - and this is correct because `GetServiceDisplayName` return size of the service's display name, *excluding the null-terminating character* - so we need extra one character space for terminating 0;

but in next line error - `&buffSize` - last parameter *lpcchBuffer* must containing size of the buffer in characters. so exactly buffer size which you allocated. but you allocate  `buffSize + 1` space, not `buffSize`. so code must be next:

```
if (SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManagerW(nullptr, nullptr, 0))
{
    DWORD cch = 0;
    if (!GetServiceDisplayNameW(hSCManager, m_serviceName, nullptr, &cch))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            PWSTR buff =(PWSTR)alloca(++cch*sizeof(WCHAR));
            if (GetServiceDisplayNameW(hSCManager, m_serviceName, buff, &cch))
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", buff);
            }
        }
    }
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
}
```

so you in your code must replace `buffSize + 1` to `++buffSize`

---

about ansi version - `GetServiceDisplayNameA` - here really error in api implementation - if buffer size in characters not big enough - it return how many **bytes** require **unicode** service name excluding the null-terminating symbol. if buffer is big enough it at all not update *lpcchBuffer*. this yet else one argument never use `A` versions of api, but always `W`

Comment: In the edit; i have pointed that buffer size must include terminating null, if it is input argument. But not well documented.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz - no documentation is clear enough. When the function returns, lpcchBuffer contains the size of the service's display name, **excluding** the null-terminating character. but even if not read documentation - anyway error in your code - you allocate `1+n` buffere size, but say to api that you have `n` buffer size. you need allocate `++n` instead `1+n`

Comment: actually my question is now; why do we get different required buffer sizes?

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz - this is not true. we all time got the same buffer size

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz - yes, `A` version containing error in implementation (not in documentation). but for what you need `A` and `TCHAR` ?

Comment: implementing x64 und unicode for an old (20 years old) ansi-x86 software. This is a long histroy to explain, but it is only backwards compatibility.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz - i think that since win2000 - no any sense use ansi. i for example use only unicode  api versions and never `TCHAR`. however i can confirm that `GetServiceDisplayNameA` containing error (test on win10). the `GetServiceDisplayNameW` work correct

Comment: Unless you target Windows 98 it makes no sense to write new code with `TCHAR`.

Comment: You found a bug in old code. This is an RPC call to `services!RGetServiceDisplayNameA`, in the services.exe process, which in turn calls `services!RGetServiceDisplayNameW`. The code is correct on entry, i.e. a double-sized temporary buffer is allocated to hold the wide-character name, and on success it converts to ANSI correctly. However, if `RGetServiceDisplayNameW` fails because the buffer is too small, it mistakenly returns the character length times 2 (i.e. `sizeof(WCHAR)`). I'm sure this isn't the only remaining bug like this. Writing ANSI wrapper functions is mind numbing.

Comment: @eryksun I found something similar by `::GetWindowTextLength()` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521(v=vs.85).aspx), but it is documented well in remarks. I think it is not a bug here, only documentation is bad. To find out to exact size of the buffer, a convert to ansi is needed, because internally it works with unicode as you said, and maybe it could be an overhead. Thank you for your help. It would be an answer, if you want to post.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz - *I think it is not a bug here, only documentation is bad.* - no, this is 100% bug in `A` shell which convert unicode result to ansi